# Accessing shared memory created in C using shmget() from Java

Tags: java, c, ipc

I have a C application in which I have a variable whose value continually changes. I need to read this value in my Java application as it changes.

I have created a shared memory segment using "shmget()" in my C program, so I have the key to access the shared memory.

How can I access this shared memory using that key in Java code?

The C code is as follows

```
char myc;
int myshmid;
key_t mykey;
char *myshm,*mys;

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  mykey=5678;
  if((myshmid=shmget(mykey,SHMSZ,IPC_CREAT | 0666))<0)
  {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
  }

  if((myshm=shmat(myshmid,NULL,0))==(char *) -1)
  {
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
  }

  mys=myshm;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code (don't forget to start each line by at least 4 spaces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. You will need to communicate with your Java code in a different way.

You could use JNI if your C and Java code can run in the same process. Otherwise, use sockets or something similar.

Comment: Can you please explain how can i use JNI?

Comment: No, there is too much to explain. Search the Internet for a tutorial. JNI is what you use to write `native` methods in C or C++, if you've ever wondered how `native` works.